# Doesn't useEffect run after the component is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set an event in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  var input = document.getElementById("emailInput");
  console.log(input); // null when reloading page!
  
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.key === 'Enter')
      onLogin();
  });
}, []);
```

Whenever I reload the page, the call to `input.addEventListener` fails because the value of `input` is `null`. It is my understanding that `useEffect` runs after the component is rendered, so the input element with `id="emailInput"` should already exist by then. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** I was rendering the element conditionally based on something assigned in `useEffect`. I did not show that part in the question, but the part not shown was the problem...

Comment: Can you show us where #emailInput is actually being rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing *should* work, so I suspect something like a spelling mistake.

However, as a general rule if `emailInput` is part of your React app, you should be storing a reference to the input in a ref.

```
const inputRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // do stuff with inputRef.current
}, [])

return <div><input ref={inputRef} /></div>
```

Even better, based on your example, and again if `emailInput` is part of your React app, you can simply add a `onKeyUp` directly as a prop. This way you can skip refs and useEffect

```
return <div><input onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have other issues (like place of input field etc.), not removing event may cause this.

Try something like this to cleanup your event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
    var input = document.getElementById("emailInput");
    console.log(input); // null when reloading page!

    const yourFunc = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      if (event.key === 'Enter') console.log('hello')
    }
    
    input.addEventListener("keyup", yourFunc);

    return () => input.removeEventListener('keyup', yourFunc)
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes useEffect runs after the component is rendered.